# SwiftでUITextFieldの入力に設定したPickerの初期値の設定方法をご教示ください

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

UITextFieldの入力にPickerを使う方法はわかるですが、初期値の設定がうまくいかず困っています。

ソースコードは後述の様な概要で、他のViewでButtonをTapしConditionViewControllerに遷移してきます。その際に前のViewでTapしたButtonの種類に応じて、初期値をPckerに設定したいと思っています。現状のソースコードでエラー無く動いています。後述には関係なさそうなコードは省略しています。

ネットやgithubで検索したところ、TextFieldを使わない状態でのPckerでの初期値設定方法は
簡単に出てくるのですが、TextFieldを使った例が出てこず困っています。

どのようにすればご教示いただきたいです。

環境
Xcode7.1

コード

```
class ConditionViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var location: UITextField!
let locationPickerView = UIPickerView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    _setPcker()

}

func _setPcker() {
    locationPickerView.delegate = self
    locationPickerView.dataSource = self
    // ここで初期値を設定しているつもりが、設定されない
    locationPickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    location.inputView = locationPickerView
}
```

Comment: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSourceに対応する関数がコードにありませんが、実際には用意されてるのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。はい、用意してあります。特にエラーなく動作もしています。

Answer (score 1):

こちらで以下のソースを使ってテストしてみましたが、問題なく初期値が設定できています。どこか、他の部分に原因があるのではないでしょうか？　（Xcode 7.2 / iOS9で確認）

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var location: UITextField!
    let locationPickerView = UIPickerView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        _setPcker()
    }

    func _setPcker() {
        locationPickerView.delegate = self
        locationPickerView.dataSource = self

        // ここで初期値を設定しているつもりが、設定されない
        locationPickerView.selectRow(5, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
        location.inputView = locationPickerView
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 120
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return "Item \(row)"
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        location.text = "Item \(row)"
    }
}
```

実行時の画面はこんな感じになりました。

[image: UIPickerViewが表示された画面]

Comment: またまた有難うございます！

どうやら自分が勘違いしていたみたいです。
初期値とは、textFieldをタップする前から設定されていて、textFieldに表示される値とは違うのですね。

私の理想では、画面を表示した時にpickerでデフォルト値が設定されていて、textFieldにも表示されていて、その値が大抵のユーザーにとって選びたい値のため、pickerをいじる手間を削減できると考えていました。

いただいたサンプルですと、一度textfieldをタップして
pickerで形式上値を選ばないといけないように思えます。

textFieldを使わずにpickerだけの場合は、初期値にカーソルがあたっていたので、てっきり自分がやりたいことが実現できると勘違いしていました。

私がやりたいと思っていることは実装可能なのでしょうか??
textFieldに初期値をいれておいて、
今教えていただいたように内部的にpickerにも値をもっておけば、
よいのでしょうか?(自分でも試してみますが、良い案があればお聞きしたいです)

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @tatsuya.yokoyama  あなたのコメントは、なにをいいたいのか、まったくこちらに伝わってきません。謎が逆に深まるばかりです。

Comment: 初期値として指定したい値を、TextFieldに設定すればいいだけなのでは無いでしょうか？